# Time Data Structure for DC.js Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm using crossfilter.js and dc.js to create a dashboard and have one chart which has been stumping me! Hopefully someone can help! See data structure below:

[Sample Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtGO9.png)

I'm trying to make chart which plots quarters like below:

[Desired Chart (Generated in Excel)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mQpC.png)

I'm trying to avoid normalizing/flattening the data set for Quarters because I would have a x4 times the amount of records (or more depending on how many years we wish to show) and there are a lot of additional description fields used as dimensions for other analysis.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: You probably need Crossfilter's groupAll. That's quite complicated, but here's a previous answer that might help you. Main difference is that you have quarters, not labels - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828083/how-to-make-row-chart-for-multilabel-data-in-dc-js/33831011#33831011

Comment: Thanks Ethan - I'll take a look!